# Unable to boot from CD: CODE 4

Tags: installation, compact-disc, dell-dimension

I'm trying to install Windows XP SP2 from a Dell green CD. I am installing it on a Dell Dimension 4100.

I used 2 CDROMs, no luck, still get the error message: **CDBOOT: Unable to boot from CDROM: Code 4.**

So, I tried another Dell CD, no luck. I tried to flash the BIOS, no luck.

I hear the CD reader spinning fast but nothing happens except the black screen with that error message.

My BIOS configuration is A1.

Comment: I've been trying with 5 Dell CDs. No luck! One Windows XP x64 and it boot from it. Someone get it?

Comment: I'm trying with WinToFlash now... I'll keep ya posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my answer but hopefully it helps:

The error code has something to do witht the type of emulation the CD is trying to use. 
The best solution to this problem is to copy your entire cd to a hard drive, use cdimage to make an .iso( go to the unnattended guide get the toolset from MSFN, it is on the finalize page), then use Nero or the like to reburn it. And try again it seems to be the boot.img files sometimes don't like the CD drive. Hope this helps.

Comment: SOURCE: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/14368-cdboot-unable-to-boot-from-cd-code-4/

Comment: This CD is ok since I've been installating it on so many computers. It's something wrong with the drive or computer.

Comment: Update: I tried 5 Dell Reinstallation CD... no one boots. I tried a Windows XP x64 and it boots!!! I really don't get it!

Answer (score 1):

Check your RAM. Reinstall it. Change the slot and try again. Code 4 is the problem it shows when it can't access memory.